# Logistic regression: do not include variable used in regression in linear equation for predicted Y

Tags: regression, logistic

I am setting up a logistic regression using the following (simplified) form:

Logit(Y) = Constant + A*x + B*z

The real-life scenario is that I am trying to understand the probability of a sales prospect converting from a phone call and x = time_from_prospect_upload_to_call and z = channel of prospect (dummy).

I include x in the model because I want to hold the time_to_call constant for calculating the other coefficients, but if I want to get the predicted Y for new prospects, is it OK to not include x in the linear equation?

Comment: logit(Y) should be logit(P(Y=1)).

Comment: You have a linear equation in the logit. You cannot remove terms and then expect the model to keep working.